# How to CORRECTLY install gsl library in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, installation, gsl

I got a problem while installing the GNU Scientific Library (gsl). 
I put the package on my desktop, and did "./configure", "make", and "sudo make install", according to the document included. I checked the /usr/local/include directory, there is a newly created "gsl" folder in there. But When I tried to use the functions provided by the library, the "undefined reference to 'gsl_sf_beta_inc'" error occurred. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>

int main (void)
{
    double a = 20;
    double b = 1000;
    double x = 0.5;
    double result = gsl_sf_beta_inc(a, b, x);
    printf("%f/d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I sensed that the problem might be caused by the fact I put the package on the desktop, so the binary code generated by the "make" command goes there, which is wrong. 
So, is my guess correct? If it is, where should I put them? If it is not, what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to link the library too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to link the library, assuming the `make install` was successful.

The [gsl's documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linking-programs-with-the-library.html#Linking-programs-with-the-library) says this should work 
(note the two necessary linking options for gsl to work: "-lgsl -lgslcblas"):

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib main.c -o main -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Alternative "cblas" instead of gsl's cblas is also possible as per: [alternate cblas for gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linking-with-an-alternative-BLAS-library.html#Linking-with-an-alternative-BLAS-library)

Comment: Thank you Dude, but it does not work. Actually, if I run the command you provided, everything will be "undefined reference"-d. But I think you pointed to a right direction. I am new to programming, so I am not familiar with this "linking" thing. I will work on that. Any further comment is welcome.

Comment: But really, if install was successful, you simply need to tweak the line I provided with the real paths (which I think are correct, since you said there is a gsl folder in /usr/src/include).

Comment: I tried this one: gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib main.c -o main -lgsl -l gslcblas, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome dude, just don't forget to accept the answer if you find it worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pkg-config --libs gsl` to find out what the necessary linkers are to be and then just link them. An optional thing would be to check `pkg-config --cflags gsl`. The second gives you the directory of the include files if they are not installed in the default `/usr/include/` directory. If you've installed it there you can just ignore that.
The output of `pkg-config --libs gsl` would be
`-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`
That means that those three have to be linked. So while compiling your program you do that by,
`gcc name.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`

Comment: More simply, you can just write `gcc -o name name.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gsl)`, or (in a reasonable Makefile) `LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs gsl)` and `CFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags gsl)`.