# g++ compilation with gsl: library not found

Tags: c++, gsl

Hi I'm trying to install and use GSL library following this guide: [Install GSL on Mac](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/10/12/using-the-gnu-scientific-library-on-a-mac/). The brew installation works fine and I can see the file in path: /usr/local/include. Then I tried with the sample c code, but when I compile it gives me this error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64. I searched and referred to this answer here: [g++ error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710183/c-compile-gsl-on-x86-64), so I added -lgsl to the command, sth like:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -lgsl main.c
```

But it gives: ld: library not found for -lgsl error. How can I resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the solution should be this:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl main.c
```

This works. Refer to the answer here:[Install GSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033927/how-to-correctly-install-gsl-library-in-linux). Basically what -I gives you is the headers, while we also need the -L statement to link the library.